# ¿Cómo creo controles programaticamente que adopten mi estilo personalizado (Material Design)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Estoy intentando crear controles con código, ya pude crearlos pero mi problema es que al crearlos estos no adoptan mi estilo personalizado que estoy usando con propiedades de material design. Adjunto una imagen donde he creado controles manualmente con diseño xml y estos adoptan sin problemas el estilo de material design pero en la parte inferior creé 3 controles(Textview, EditText y RadioButton) con código java los cuales no han adoptado el estilo. El problema pasa en la Api 19 o inferior, en la Api 21 en adelante no tengo este problema.

[image: Podemos ver que los controles en la parte inferior no adoptan el estilo]

---

Hice todo lo que me indicaron y no hallo resultados, sigue lo mismo, dejo mi código que estoy usando.

```
package com.ejemplo.probandoo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];

    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    //rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rb[i].setText("foo bar");
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
    }
    hourButtonLayout.addView(rg);
}}
```

Ese es mi código y el resultado es el mismo no adopta mi estilo personalizado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mírate si te sirve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046878/setting-styles-of-programmatically-added-views

Answer (score 13, accepted):

El usuario tenia originalmente un layout similar a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual deseaba cambiar los colores del layout y controles.

Para lograr esto, se tienen que cambiar los colores del tema que definen la aplicación, el tema se define en el `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <application
        ...
        ...
        ...       
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Este tema debe estar definido dentro de `\values\styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

y los colores definidos dentro de `\values\colors.xml` deben ser (obtuve colores RGB similares a los de tu imagen anexa en la pregunta):

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#F54834</color>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<color name="colorAccent">#F54834</color>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al editar los valores para `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` y `colorAccent` , se obtiene como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### * Nota importante:Los colores mostrados en esta imagen son obtenidos de la imagen que originalmente se tenia en la pregunta, y que fue eliminada por el OP.

---

## Como cambiar color de RadioButtons y CheckBox creados programaticamente en API 19 o menor.

Al parecer **existe un problema al cambiar el color de los controles en API 19 o menor mediante el tema, esto si los controles son creados programaticamente**.

Agrego este método el cual en realidad funciona para todas las versiones ya que usamos las clases [AppCompatRadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.html) y [AppCompatCheckBox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckBox.html)

Con esto no se tendrá ningún problema en cambiar el color de nuestros controles creados programaticamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo el código para realizar el ejemplo mostrado en la imagen:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        AppCompatRadioButton[] rb = new AppCompatRadioButton[5];
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            rb[i]  = new AppCompatRadioButton(this);
            rb[i].setText("Radio"+i);
            rb[i].setId(i + 100);
            rg.addView(rb[i]);
        }

        AppCompatCheckBox[] cb = new AppCompatCheckBox[5];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            cb[i]  = new AppCompatCheckBox(this);
            cb[i].setText("Check"+i);
            cb[i].setId(i + 100);
            rg.addView(cb[i]);
        }
        hourButtonLayout.addView(rg);

    }
}
```

En el layout agregamos el `RadioGroup`:

```
  <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Al parecer no leíste completamente el post, claro que funciona con eso pero a partir de la api 21 en adelante; mi problema como menciono en los comentarios es que no funciona esto en la api 19 o inferior.

Comment: En la pregunta no mencionas sobre api 19.

Comment: Sí se me pasó eso, ya que después descubrí que era el tema de la Api, pero lo hice en un comentario de una respuesta. Gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score 5):

Sin realizar nada es decir de un proyecto generado por android studio,

Muestra donde se crearán los controles

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Java para crear controles dinámicos

```
private void createRadioButton() {
    ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    //rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rb[i].setText("foo bar");
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
    }
    hourButtonLayout.addView(rg);

}
```

A mi me ha creado 5 radiobuttons con el `colorAccent` definido a `style` cuando están activados.

Si quieres forzar que los controles tenga otro color diferente del `colorAccent`
en `styles.xml` añadir

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
```

Extraido de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat)

La actividad debe tener el tema asignando.

**Testeado en dispositivo real:**

- Moto G con Lollipop 5.0.1

Comment: Hice exactamente lo que mencionas pero el resultado es el mismo, cuando lo creo con XML adoptan el estilo sin problemas, pero con el código java no adopta mi Estilo, uso un emulador con Api 19.

Comment: prueba con http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843098/android-appcompat-v721-0-0-change-material-checkbox-colors recuerda que la actividad debe extenderse de AppCompatActivity

Comment: Hola la Actividad extiende de AppCompatActivity, no entiendo porque no hereda el estilo.

Comment: Otra manera para ver que pasa, crea un proyecto nuevo que solo tenga lo de agregar raidobuttons a ver si allí heredan el estilo, tambien puede ser cosa del emulador. Yo lo estoy probando en mi dispositivo con Android L

Comment: Si eso hice cree un proyecto nuevo, y nada, acabo de postear una respuesta donde muestro mi código y el mismo resultado que me da.

Answer (score -3):

Estimados gracias a todos por su colaboración, al final mi solución fue usar los widget's de Appcompat directamente para que no haya problemas de incompatibilidad con versiones anteriores a la api 19; les dejo mi código:

```
package com.starttec.probandoo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    AppCompatRadioButton[] rb = new AppCompatRadioButton[5];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        rb[i]  = new AppCompatRadioButton(MainActivity.this,null,R.attr.radioButtonStyle);
        rb[i].setText("foo bar");
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
    }
    hourButtonLayout.addView(rg);
}
}
```

Les dejo el link de referencia:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.html